# How to get the build jobs using Azure DevOps REST APi?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

So, I can get the build details, but it does not contain any info on the build jobs. E.g. Each build job has run on a build agent - how can I get this piece using REST Api?

We are talking about a vNext build, not XAML.

Answer (score 6):

You can find all tasks and jobs in timeline records: [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). You can paste into browser this template to check results for a specific build:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds/%7BbuildId%7D/timeline)

I use [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) package and this is example for it:

```csharp
    static void PrintTimeLine(string TeamProjectName, int BuildId)
    {
        var timeline = BuildClient.GetBuildTimelineAsync(TeamProjectName, BuildId).Result;

        if (timeline.Records.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task Name-----------------------------Start Time---Finish Time---Result");
            foreach(var record in timeline.Records)
                if (record.RecordType == "Task")
                Console.WriteLine("{0, -35} | {1, -10} | {2, -10} | {3}",
                    (record.Name.Length < 35) ? record.Name : record.Name.Substring(0, 35), 
                    (record.StartTime.HasValue) ? record.StartTime.Value.ToLongTimeString() : "",
                    (record.FinishTime.HasValue) ? record.FinishTime.Value.ToLongTimeString() : "",
                    (record.Result.HasValue) ? record.Result.Value.ToString() : "");
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/19.TFRestApiAppQueueBuild/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs

Comment: Does it let you know the build agent used for the particular build job?

Comment: Each Record contains the workerName member. Maybe it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}` will let you know the Agent used under the object `queue` and there it shows the agent queue (91) number and the pool id (8)

```json
"queue":{  
      "id":91,
      "name":"MotBuild-Default",
      "pool":{  
         "id":8,
         "name":"MotBuild-Default"
      }
```

Use

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool_id}?api-version=5.0-preview.1` or `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/queues/{queue_id}` will return the pool.

So now using `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool_id}/agents` will return a LIST of agents under the Agent Pools

Now that I've explained all that let's try to tie everything together.

1. Use `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}` and find the Queue and Pool IDs.
2. use `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline` and find the record of type `Job` and the property `workerName` which will return NAME of the Agent used.
3. Query the Agents with `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool_id}/agents` and find the agent `id` by filtering the `name` from the name found in step #2 above.
4. Finally query `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool_id}/agents/{agent_id}` will return a high-level info of the agent, not much info.

*This next api is undocumented*

5. To get the detailed capabilities query `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool_id}/agents/{agent_id}?includeCapabilities=true` which a huge result set will be returned!!  **I think this is what you want.**

Read more about the APIs at:

- [Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
- [Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
- [Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)